# Ansible windows unzip module is failing, how to fix that?

Tags: windows, ansible

My task part of playbook.

```
- name: unzip maven
     win_unzip:
       src: C:\tools\maven.zip
       dest: C:\tools\maven
       recurse: yes
       delete_archive: yes
```

output:

```
TASK [unzip maven] *******************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: ansible_winrm_cert_validation unsupported by pywinrm (is an up-to-date version of pywinrm
installed?)
[WARNING]: ansible_winrm_cert_validation unsupported by pywinrm (is an up-to-date version of pywinrm
installed?)
fatal: [build-machine3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\tools\\maven", "msg": "PowerShellCommunityExtensions PowerShell Module (PSCX) is required for non-'.zip' compressed archive types.", "removed": false, "src": "C:\\tools\\maven.zip"}
fatal: [build-machine2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\tools\\maven", "msg": "PowerShellCommunityExtensions PowerShell Module (PSCX) is required for non-'.zip' compressed archive types.", "removed": false, "src": "C:\\tools\\maven.zip"}
```

So added the PSCX part before it.

```
- name: Install PSCX
     win_psmodule:
       name: Pscx
       state: present
```

But, got below error now related to Pscx.

```
TASK [Install PSCX] ******************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: ansible_winrm_cert_validation unsupported by pywinrm (is an up-to-date version of pywinrm
installed?)
[WARNING]: ansible_winrm_cert_validation unsupported by pywinrm (is an up-to-date version of pywinrm
installed?)
fatal: [build-machine3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Problems installing Pscx module: The following commands are already available on this system:'gcb,Expand-Archive,Format-Hex,Get-Hash,help,prompt,Get-Clipboard,Get-Help,Set-Clipboard'. This module 'Pscx' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'Pscx', use -AllowClobber parameter.", "nuget_changed": false, "output": "", "repository_changed": false}
fatal: [build-machine2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Problems installing Pscx module: The following commands are already available on this system:'gcb,Expand-Archive,Format-Hex,Get-Hash,help,prompt,Get-Clipboard,Get-Help,Set-Clipboard'. This module 'Pscx' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'Pscx', use -AllowClobber parameter.", "nuget_changed": false, "output": "", "repository_changed": false}
```

Please suggest.

I added this question to stackoverflow first but it got closed there and redirected me here.

Comment: Check to see if the maven.zip file is actually a zip file.

Comment: Yes it is a zip file only.I am able to extract it manually

Comment: This is the target zip file https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip